# Wordpress How to send an "Set Password" E-Mail to users that got imported by script

Tags: wordpress, authentication, passwords

I try to send an "Set your Password" mail, which I can customise, for a Site with a custom user role "Händler", in WordPress. These users get imported via script and XML-File.

So I want, when the script adds these ≈1200 users and they aren´t already present, to automatically or on button click receive an email with a link, where they can set a password for that user.
So it needs to work like a "Verification-process", because only when these users have set their password and accept that way, that they show up on the website.

I tried some Plugins already, but none of them fits my needs completely.

Plugins I already tried:

- Import and export users and customers
- User Verification (thats almost right, but their is no chance to let the user set an password, instead of just activating their account)

Can anyone point me in the right direction here, cause I googled for some time now, but nothing helped me yet.

Thanks for your help, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this particular problem.
I loop through the users with the custom user role and send them via wp_mail() the "Reset Password" Mail with custom content.

```
function mm_send_password_reset_mail(){
    $users = get_users( array( 'role' => array( 'haendler' ) ) );
    $output = '';
    foreach ( $users as $useri ) {
        $user = get_user_by('id', $useri->ID);
        $firstname = $user->first_name;
        $email = $user->user_email;
        $adt_rp_key = get_password_reset_key( $user );
        $user_login = $user->user_login;
        $rp_link = '<a href="' . network_site_url("wp-login.php?action=rp&key=$adt_rp_key&login=" . rawurlencode($user_login), 'login') . '">Passwort vergeben</a>';
        
        $output .= $user->user_email;
    
        if ($firstname == "") $firstname = "Händler";
        $message = "Hallo ".$firstname.",<br>";
        $message .= "Sie wurden auf der Seite ".get_bloginfo( 'name' )." als Händler angelegt mit der E-Mail-Adresse ".$email."<br>";
        $message .= "Klicken Sie hier, wenn Sie damit einverstanden sind, das Sie auf der Webseite als Händler öffentlich aufgelistet werden: <br>";
        $message .= $rp_link.'<br>';
    
       $subject = __("Vergeben Sie ein Passwort für ".get_bloginfo( 'name'));
       $headers = array();
    
       add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', function( $content_type ) {return 'text/html';});
       wp_mail( $email, $subject, $message, $headers);
    
       // Reset content-type to avoid conflicts -- http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/23578
       remove_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'set_html_content_type' );
   }
   echo json_encode(array('user' => $output));
    die();
}
```

I added a custom link in the admin toolbar and call the above function via ajax. That works like a charm.

Thanks anyway.